# How to get a value into a variable after click on text

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a form with HTML, CSS and PHP.

The idea is select an option from a dropbox and choose a day on a calendar.

However, I don't know how to send a value to a variable in php by clicking on a day.

With the value in the variable, I will insert it into a database.

[Here is a photo of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi5XQ.png)

Here is my code:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<div class="from-group mb-3">
    <label for="">Select an option:</label>
    <select name="name" class="form-control">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <table style="width:25%">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="12.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a></td>
            <td colspan="2">January</td>
            <td><a href="2.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sun</td>
            <td>Mon</td>
            <td>Tue</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Thu</td>
            <td>Fri</td>
            <td>Sat⠀</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="gray">27</td>
            <td class="gray">28</td>
            <td class="gray">29</td>
            <td class="gray">30</td>
            <td class="gray">31</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td class="gray">1</td>
            <td class="gray">2</td>
            <td class="gray">3</td>
            <td class="gray">4</td>
            <td class="gray">5</td>
            <td class="gray">6</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="from-group mb-3">
    <button type="submit" name="save_select" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'calendar');
$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$day = $_POST['day'];

$query = "INSERT INTO ferias (name, day, year, month, week, dateferia, recordtype, time) 
VALUES ('$name', '$day', '123', '1', '1', '2021-01-01', '6', '1')";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if($query_run){
    $_SESSION['status'] = "inserted successfully";
    header("Location: ../1.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['status'] = "not inserted";
    header("Location: ../1.php");
}
```

I have a variable called $day, so, for example, when I click on number 1, I want this value to go to the variable.

Someone knows how to do that?

Comment: better use a js plungin/library, a date picker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ but you can with JS put an event listener on the click and assign the value to a hidden input in the form and submit it

Comment: In pure PHP, the easiest way is to use $_GET, so you'd link to ?day=18 for example.

Comment: Robo Robok, I see, but first i need to give a value to each number and then i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input `type=date` if you want date, you made it very complex here.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" name='myform'>
<div class="from-group mb-3">
    <label for="">Select an option:</label>
    <select name="name" class="form-control">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="main">
<input type="date" name="day">
<button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
</div>
</form>
```

This will post the data to `insert.php` in the format `{ name=option1, day=2021-09-07}`

Now you can do some tweaks with `day`

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'calendar');
$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['day'];

$newday = explode("-", $date);
$day = $newday[2];// in the array {2021,09,07}
echo $day;// for debugging....

// Continue you code here.....
```

This is my way of doing, if you really want to submit the form when click of that number just add `onclick` event on each day.

```
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">3</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">4</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">5</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">6</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">7</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">8</td>
            <td onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()">9</td>
```

This is the easiest way of doing it but I still don't know how it gonna be posted in `day` variable of `post` data